# Load-Balancing into Multiple Database

Tags: azure, union, load-balancing

What is the best way to load-balance requests into multiple SQL database from .Net environment?

We have a web application that keep surprising us with upcoming traffic. Now, we moved logs/analytics outside our operational database.

I am using SQL SE 2014 ([uniondb package](http://partitiondb.com/union-mode/)). 4 DBs, ~1.5T volume per one. I am not using any cluster-replication solutions as my clients come and go. We plan on moving to Azure in the following year (*but it will definitely take time*).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [NetScaler](http://www.citrix.com/products/netscaler-application-delivery-controller/tech-info.html)?

See the following document - Scaling and Optimizing
[Microsoft SQL Server with
Citrix NetScaler](https://www.citrix.com/content/dam/citrix/en_us/documents/products-solutions/scaling-and-optimizing-microsoft-sql-server-with-citrix-netscaler.pdf)

> Scaling-up helps Microsoft SQL database servers take
>   advantage of faster CPU, memory and I/O; however, server connection
>   capacity remains a bottleneck which effectively limits the number of
>   databases that can be hosted on a server. NetScaler’s SQL connection
>   management effectively scales-up database infrastructure in several
>   ways.
>
> Load balancing – With SQL transaction awareness, NetScaler can route
>   one client’s many SQL transactions in a single connection to several
>   different servers, allowing for more optimal load balancing of SQL
>   traffic.